# Download PDF using any cloud and grant access only to a particular person

Tags: node.js, cloud, devops, pdf-generation, nodemailer

In my project, I need to send a link to the user through which they can download a PDF. To send the PDF, we'll need to send an email to the user. In the email template, we'll include the link for PDF download, and the user should be able to open it. We want to create a link from our end that can only be accessed personally through email. We've used Node.js for this purpose.